# Div/Picture doesn't resize properly on zoom

Tags: html, css

I have left and right arrows defined by an image inside a div. All my div heights and widths are defined in percentages. When I zoom in or out of the site (using Chrome) all the elements behave as I would expect them to except these left and right arrows (i.e. the div the image is in) which don't seem to scale the same as everything else.

I've created a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TN2L4/) to show what I mean. When you zoom out I would expect the arrow image to get smaller but this doesn't seem to happen.

Below is the relevant HTML

```html
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="leftSideBar">

    <div class="miniLogo">
        <img src="icons/miniLogo.png" height="140" width="140" alt="Logo" />
    </div>

    <div id="mainMenu" class="navMenu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="splashNav"><a id="a1" href="Welcome.php">WELCOME</a></li><br />
                <li class="splashNav"><a id="a2" href="Portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a></li><br />
                <li class="splashNav"><a id="a3" href="Contact.php">CONTACT</a></li> <br />
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="projectMenu" >
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="projectNav"><a class="projectLink" href="?project=im licab">IM LICAB</a></li><li class="projectNav"><a class="projectLink" href="?project=project2">PROJECT2</a></li><li class="projectNav"><a class="projectLink" href="?project=project3">PROJECT3</a></li>                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="navArrow">
        <img src="icons/Click Left.png" alt="Left Arrow" class="hoverOver" onclick="nextPic('L')" />
    </div>
    <div class="coverPic">
    <img class="projectCoverPic" src="projects/im licab/IMALICKABLEGUY1.jpg" alt="Project Cover Picture" />     </div>
    <div class="navArrow">
        <img src="icons/Click Right.png" alt="Right Arrow" class="hoverOver" onclick="nextPic('R')" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rightSideBar">
    <div class="projectDesc"><p>Description</p>

<p>Paragraph1</p>

<p>Paragraph2</p>

<p>Paragraph3</p>
</div>  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS

```css
html, body {
margin:0; padding:0;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
}

body {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


h1 {
text-align:center;
}

a:link{
text-decoration: none;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
}

.hoverOver:hover {
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
}

.container {
width:90%; 
height: 95%;
min-height: 95%;
max-height: 95%;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
}

.leftSideBar {
width: 14%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

.rightSideBar {
width: 20%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 8%;
}

.navMenu {
width: 100%;
height: 30%;
}

.main {
margin-top: 10%;
margin-right: 4%;
margin-left: 4%;
padding: 0;
height: 70%;
min-height: 70%;
max-height: 70%;
width: 56%;
float: left;
}

.splashNav {
list-style-type: none;
}

#a1{
color: #9B9B9B;
}

#a2{
color: #AFAFAF;
}

#a3{
color: #BFBFBF;
}

#a1:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #737373;
}

#a1:active{
text-decoration: none;
color: #737373;
}

#a2:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #737373;
}

#a2:active{
text-decoration: none;
color: #737373;
}

#a3:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: #737373;
}

#a3:active{
text-decoration: none;
color: #737373;
}

#logo {
display: block;
margin: auto;
    transform-origin: top left; /* IE 10+, Firefox, etc. */
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left; /* Chrome */
    -ms-transform-origin: top left; /* IE 9 */
}

#welcomeMenu{
margin-top: 100%;
}

#contactPhoto{
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

#mainMenu {
margin-top: 10%;
}

.miniLogo {
margin-top: 40%;
margin-left: 5%;
}

.projectNav {
list-style-type: none;
}

.projectLink {
color: black;
font-size: 70%;
margin-left: 15%;
}

.projectDesc {
float: right;
font-size: 85%;
margin-top: 55%;
}

.coverPic {
margin: auto;
margin-top: -6.5%;
float: left;
max-width: 88%;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
}

.projectCoverPic {
max-width: 100%;
}

.navArrow {
float: left;
margin: auto;
margin-top: -5.5%;
max-width: 2.5%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've set it's height to `100%` explicitly so it's width is `auto` and it'll always have a sufficient width to keep the aspect ratio, but since you also have set `max-width:2.5%` it can't grow beyond that either, which is the size you are looking at...

Comment: Well 2.5% gives me the correct size I want relative to everything else initially but I thought the whole point of defining it 'relatively' using percentages was that it would increase and decrease proportionate to the site as a whole (like everything else is). I've tried using just 'Width' property instead too but that didn't work either - how can I keep it that relative size but have it zoom normally?

Comment: So if I remove the height completely so that it's auto and I change max-width to width that should work right? It gives me the same result though

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome zooming to me. If you change the width of the window it scales as you want it, but it does not work when zooming.

Comment: for me it's changing in chrome if i remove the set height... http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/TN2L4/7/embedded/result/

Comment: Seems like you've removed the container divs completely in that jfiddle?

Comment: @db579 dosen't matter.. they'll change with the container divs also.. http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/TN2L4/9/embedded/result/

Comment: Hmm I notice when i load it in chrome on my phone your solution works perfectly for me too, on my Ubuntu Chromium (build 33.0.1750.152) still not working - bug in that particular version perhaps? Leo can i ask which version you're running?